# Visual Studio 2015 hanging when placing UI elements (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently installed VS2015 Pro and it works fine other than placing a UI element down when designing a WPF application causes VS to hang for a good 10-20 seconds before continuing to work normally. This occurs for every UI element I place.

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you have all the updates. i know there were some issues with the designer before the updates.

Comment: Brand new install, completely up to date.

Comment: Any extensions or plugins?

Comment: Only things that come with the VS installer, such as Cordova and Git